# How to make a button hide a qtip tooltip?

Tags: jquery, qtip2

There are 2 pictures (inline svg) on a page that are toggled by a buttons. When click a button the second picture appears instead the first one. Click next button - appears the first picture again. Both pictures have qtip tooltips.
Problem is that: I open tooltip (clicking a polygon on the picture) on the 1st picture and then toggle the second picture - tooltip of the 1st picture does not disappear.

Tried to bind "hide" event to a button:

```
  $('.btn-green').qtip('hide');
```

Tried this:

```
$(".btn-green").on("mouseenter", "polygon.qtip-close", function(){
        $('polygon').qtip('api').hide();
});
```

Here's a code that shows a tooltip after click a polygon or a path of a picture:

```
$('path.gipermarket, polygon.gipermarket').qtip({
content: {
    text: 'some content',
    button: 'Close'</div>'
},
show: {
    event: 'click',
    solo: true,
},
hide: {
    event: 'click'
},
// hide: {
//     leave: false
// },

position: {
    /*my: 'bottom center',
    at: 'top left'*/
    my: 'bottom center',
    at: 'center center'
},
style: {
    classes: 'border-radius'
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using `qtip.destroy()` verus `hide()` ?

Or `$(".qtip").remove()`;

Update your code to something like this

```
    events: {
        render: function () { },
        hide: function (event, api) {
            var $qtip = api;
            $qtip.destroy();
        },
        show: function () { }
    },
```

Here is an entire qtip definition

```
$target.qtip({
            style: {
                //width: 350,
                classes: 'qtip-largerText'
            },
            id: 'YouQtipID',
            content: {
                global: false,
                text: function (event, api) {
                    api.set('content.text', 'Loading...');
                    return $.ajax({
                        url: '/whatever',
                        data: { SetID: setid, Abbv: abv },
                        type: 'POST',
                    }).then(
                        function (data) {
                            api.set('content.text', data);
                        }, function (xhr, status, error) {
                            var $qtip = api;
                            $qtip.destroy();
                        });
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Set',
                    button: false
                }
            },
            position: {
                my: 'top left',
                at: 'left top',
                target: $target,
                viewport: $(window)
            },
            show: {
                delay: 500,
                event: event.type,
                ready: true,
                modal: false,
                solo: true
            },
            events: {
                render: function () { },
                hide: function (event, api) {
                    var $qtip = api;
                    $qtip.destroy();
                },
                show: function () { }
            },
        }, $target);
```

Comment: I've added some of my code above. Where should I put "$(".qtip").remove();"? I can' t understand: is there a way to bind close method to any element?

Comment: Added your snippet after "style", now it looks like this:style: {
     classes: 'border-radius'
    },

    events: {
        render: function () { },
        hide: function (event, api) {
            var $qtip = api;
            $qtip.destroy();
        },
        show: function () { }
    }

Comment: @user3601990 I have added a complete sample for you.

Answer (score 0):

I've added:

```
...

events: {
    show: function() {
        $('.btn-green').one("click", function() { $(".odezhda-i-belyo").qtip('hide'); });
    }
},
....
```

But does not work.